# Issue while receiving msg from WCF-SQL Adapter

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am receiving a message from WCF-SQL Adapter in Biztalk 2006 R2 , If the message fails in Receive Pipeline XML Dissambler stage  ,pipeline gets stuck in Started State and i am not able to track the message using error routing set on the receive port but if i receive the same message by File Adapter i am able to track the Message . What could be the issue with WCF-SQL Adapter ? Am i missing some configuration ?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Only we can see it HAT. There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "InterfaceName, InterfaceName.Pipelines, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0dc53b06eee6ab25" Source: "Pipeline " Receive Port: "PortName" URI: "mssql://./ISDEV/DB_TEST" Reason: The required attribute 'zip' is missing.

Comment: So the same error occurs with both Adapters, but it gets stuck only when coming from the WCF SQL Adapter?  I can't really think of a reason for that.

Comment: Can you create a sample project that reproduces the error and share that with us?